# Is there a terminological difference between "sequence" and "complex" in homology theory

Tags: terminology, homological-algebra

Suppose you are given something like this:

$\dots \longrightarrow A^n \longrightarrow A^{n+1} \longrightarrow \dots$

People tend to talk about "chain complexes" but about "short exact sequences". Is there any terminological difference or any convention with regards to using these words (EDIT: I mean "complex" and "sequence" in a homological context) that a mathematical writer should comply to?

Answer (score 2):

A small remark: the sequence $...\rightarrow A_n\rightarrow A_{n+1}\rightarrow A_{n+2}\rightarrow A_{n+3}\rightarrow ...$ can be "exact" or a "complex" (it depends on the nature of the maps, as confirmed in the answer by @exitingcorpse), but not a "short exact sequence".

Short exact sequences (of $R$-modules, for example, denoting by $R$ a given ring) are exact sequences of the form  $0\rightarrow A\stackrel{\alpha}{\rightarrow} B\stackrel{\beta}{\rightarrow} C \rightarrow 0$; from the definition of exact sequence *plus* the shortness condition it follows that $ker(\beta)=im(\alpha)$, and $\alpha$ is injective and $\beta$ is surjective.

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ be a ring. A chain complex is a sequence (of left $R$-modules)
$A = \cdots\to A_{n}\xrightarrow{d} A_{n-1}\xrightarrow{d}\cdots$
Such that $d^2 = 0$. This allows you to define $H_n(A) = \ker{d_n}/\mathrm{im}~d_{n+1}$.

An exact complex is a chain complex such that $H_n(A) = 0$ for all $n$. Exact complexes are usually called *acyclic complexes*.

A short exact sequence is an *exact* chain complex of the form $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$. This is equivalent to saying $A\to B$ is an injection, and $B\to C$ is a surjection whose kernel is the image of $A$ under $A\to B$.

Answer (score 0):

To say that the sequence is a chain complex is a less imposing condition: it simply says that if you compose any two of the maps in the sequence, you get $0$. But to say the sequence is exact says more: it says this is precisely (or, if you rather, *exactly*) the only way you get something mapping to zero.

The first statement says that the image of the arrow to the left of $A^n$ is contained in the kernel of the arrow to its right, the second statement says that the reverse inclusion also holds.